# No Notification from Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware-orion

I am working with the Orion Context Broker and wanna get notifications for the following subscription, added to `orion.lab.fiware.org:1026`:

```
curl -v orion.lab.fiware.org:1026/v2/subscriptions -X POST -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header "X-Auth-Token: <myToken>" -d @- <<EOF 
{
  "description": "A subscription to get info about Room1",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
"id": "11582",        
"type": "User"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "temperature"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://<myIPAddress>:8080"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "temperature"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}
EOF
```

myToken: the token generated by the FIWARE server

myIPAddress: the IP address of my PC

However, in my sample HTTP server program (Node.js) on port 8080 I do not receive any notifications. I should note that after adding the above subscription, I add the entity with id 11582 through another POST request to `orion.lab.fiware.org:1026/v2/entities`.

When I read later the added subscription, it confirms that the notification has been sent (through lastNotification):

```
{
  "id": "5768088c70dce43aa351cf9b",
  "description": "A subscription to get info about Room1",
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
  "status": "active",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "11582",
        "idPattern": "",
        "type": "User"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "temperature"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "timesSent": 1,
    "lastNotification": "2016-06-20T15:16:04.00Z",
    "attrs": [
      "temperature"
    ],
    "attrsFormat": "normalized",
    "http": {
      "url": "http://<myIPAddress>:8080"
    }
  },
  "throttling": 5
}
```

Any idea why I do not receive the notification i my HTTP server program? My firewall is also off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [following tes](https://gist.github.com/fgalan/0f1814890f5f6142135890d4ee79655c)t has been donde in orion.lab.fiware.org. The termina1l.txt file shows the subscriptions and entity creation request sent to Orion (note we use localhost:10026, as the test has been done in the orion.lab.fiware.org host itself) and terminal2.txt file shows the notification received at the listener process (`nc`).

We have also done the same test (using `UserTest2` type this time) running the listener on a VM machine at FIWARE Lab (which IP cannot be disclosed for security reasons) with the 1028 port openend in the Security Group and everything worked fine again, getting:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
user-agent: orion/1.2.1 libcurl/7.19.7
host: 130.206.112.29:1028
accept: application/json
content-length: 146
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
fiware-correlator: 0870b41c-378d-11e6-910f-52540003a38e
ngsiv2-attrsformat: normalized
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive

{"subscriptionId":"5768ff6a70dce43aa351cfaa","data":[{"id":"11582","type":"UserTest2","temperature":{"type":"Float","value":23.5,"metadata":{}}}]}
```

Thus, I understand that something between orion.lab.fiware.org and your process is blocking the traffic. Note that apart for the firewall running in your machine (which you mention is off) another firewall layer could be blocking (e.g. FIWARE cloud or AWS cloud security group, coorporate firewalls, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I discovered that my IP/Server is not accessible from other networks. I couldn't discover the cause, but I have now tested through an Amazon AWS Ubuntu instance and it works! My httserver is accessible and it receives notifications from Orion.

Comment: You're welcome! If you found useful my answer please accept it and upvote. It is not to feed my ego ;) but to help other users showing that the answer is correct.

Comment: I tried to vote you immediately after I wrote my reply, but since I have not earned enough reputation, Stack overflow does not consider my vote :-( :-), sorry!